# SQL Server to Oracle query convert

Tags: sql-server, oracle, t-sql

i have a code in sql server like this

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM address WHERE new_add=new_add)
    UPDATE address set old_add=old_add);
ELSE
    UPDATE address set old_add=new_add);
```

Its working properly in SQL Server. But its not working in oracle. It shows

```
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "IF EXISTS ..." - rest of line ignored.
```

Plese help me to change this query from SQL to Oracle. Thanks

Comment: I suspect you have oversimplified your query.  But you have done it to the point where the query doesn't make sense.  Why is the query comparing the same column to itself?  Why is it setting the same column to itself?  The `update` is a no-op.

Comment: can you explain what is the `old_add` and `new_add`?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 1 FROM address WHERE new_add=new_add

if @@RowCount > 0
 UPDATE address set old_add=old_add
```

Answer (score 0):

In both databases, you can write the query as:

```
update address
    set old_add = old_add
    where exists  (SELECT * FROM address WHERE new_add = new_add);
```

The `if` is not needed at all.

However, this query is non-sensical.  It either sets a column to itself in all rows (if the condition in the `where` matches at least one row).  Or, it updates no rows (if the condition in the `where` has no matching rows).  In either case, nothing really happens.

Comment: Hey! Thanks. Its working in oracle. Thank u so much. I have one more doubt! How to add else part in this query.?

Comment: Use `not` exists.  @Sesuraj . . . Your query makes *no sense*.  Please ask another question, with sample data and desired output.